# How do I see if a HTMLElement is of a viewable kind?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I list for example `document.body.children` I get some elements that can be shown on the screen (like `<div>`) and some that can not be shown (like `<script>`).

Is there a (future) safe way to find out if an element can be shown on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements are "viewable":

```html
<style> * { display: block; } </style>
<script> // even scripts </script>
```

So either check if they are currently visible, by checking their computed style (I'll let you decide which properties you should check since even "visible" can have several interpretations), or use a list of known elements that are *usually*  not rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The future may change in terms of other methods available but currently you could simply exclude the script by doing:

```js
elements = Array.from(document.body.children).map(item => item.tagName != 'SCRIPT')
```

Add conditions for other types you want to exclude until you reach your desired 'viewable' collection.