# Optimal way to retrieve HTML nodes having text using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to get all the HTML nodes having text in an optimal way without having to loop through every node?

In other words, grab all HTML nodes having visible text.

For example, if I have a dom as below

```
<div>
    <span>Hello This is a Text Span</span>
    <div>
        <p> This is a text Paragraph</p>
        <button> This is Button Label</button>
    </div>
<div> This is also a visible text</div>
</div>
```

I should select

1. **span** having text *Hello This is a Text Span*
2. **p** having text *This is a text Paragraph*
3. **button** having text *This is Button Label*
4. **div** having text *This is also a visible text*

The outermost div in the above example doesn't have text of its own so should not be part of the result.

Edit: What problem am I trying to solve?

The framework I use escapes HTML characters in labels of fields, buttons, headings etc.

For example: **<** is converted to **& lt;'**

So I am trying to write a client side code which triggers after the page is completely rendered which will unescape all the HTML texts to a readable format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By that logic, does the wrapping `div` should be selected?

Comment: The optimal way would be to assign them a specific class, but even then you might need to loop through the elements in that class later.

Comment: What do you call "visible text"? From the DOM point of view,  `<script>console.log('hey')</script>` is the same as `<div>console.log('hey')</div>`, that one is not displayed is a CSS thing, [which can get overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64493731/3702797). Then, you need to define more clearly your constraints, what happens in the case `<div>in div<span>also in div</span></div>`? Does the <div> get matched? how many times?

Comment: The wrapping div should not be shown as it does not have any text directly visible from it.@AlonEitan

Comment: What do you mean without looping, There's no css selector to fetch your query

Answer (score 0):

The DOM property holds a numeric code indicating the node's type; text nodes use the code `3`, So you can find those text nodes by filtering them having `nodeType` `3`.

1. Wrap your all nodes in a div by giving a class.
2. Select your content by it's class like this: `$(".getTextNodes").contents();`.
3. Filter contents having `nodeType 3`.

```js
selectedElement = $(".getTextNodes").contents();

textNodes = selectedElement.filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
});

console.log(textNodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="getTextNodes">
    <span>Hello This is a Text Span</span>
    <div>
        <p> This is a text Paragraph</p>
        <button> This is Button Label</button>
    </div>
    <div> This is also a visible text</div>
</div>
```

Check [this link](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) out to read more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using just only vanilla js
My algorithm is just select all element that has no element inside it
It means select all element that has directly Text Node

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('div,span,p,button');
var arr = [];
el.forEach(function(m){
  
  if (m.querySelectorAll('div,span,p,button').length == 0){
    arr.push(m)
    console.log(m)
  }
})

// console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Hello This is a Text Span</span>
    <div>
        <p>This is a text Paragraph</p>
        <button> This is Button Label</button>
    </div>
    <div>This is also a visible text</div>
</div>
```

Jsfidle link [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/6e8yoxu5/)

> There's no css selector to get your needs and looping is only the solution.